# Make file dependency chart with multiple dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile

I am very new to make files and am trying to draw a dependency chart for my program and could use some help figuring out the particulars of these dependencies.  I am referencing [this](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/) sort of chart, but my program contains "deeper" layers of dependencies than that example and I'm unsure how these should be treated in a make file.  I'm after something like [this](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/Makefile).

My program structure is as follows:
[image: Program Dependency]

where the arrows mean the header file at the arrow head is included in that of the arrow tail.  There are no derived classes, if that matters.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You could try to achieve s.th. like this using doxygen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection, your makefile should look something like this:

```
main: main.o ChiSquared.o StatTests.o ChiSquaredTest.o KS.o ChiSquared.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main $^

ChiSquared.o: ChiSquared.cpp ChiSquared.h GaussQuad.h

ChiSquaredTest.o: ChiSquaredTest.cpp ChiSquaredTest.h ChiSquared.h GaussQuad.h

KS.o: KS.cpp KS.h ChiSquared.h GaussQuad.h

StatTests.o: StatTests.cpp StatTests.h ChiSquaredTest.h KS.h ChiSquared.h GaussQuad.h

Main.o: Main.cpp  StatTests.h ChiSquaredTest.h KS.h ChiSquared.h GaussQuad.h
```

(Note the use of the automatic variable `$^` instead of an explicit list of the object files.)

Be aware of two things:

1) I'll bet you don't actually need to `#include` all those header files in each other; too much use of `#include` at high levels causes unnecessary dependency, which leads to unnecessary rebuilding.

2) There's no need to maintain these prerequisite lists in the makefile by hand; Make can do it for you. But that's an advanced technique, so let's get your simple makefile working first.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to add some compiling commands for each make rule, but it seems to be working.  As for the `#include`'s, is there a better way if the class that is including another class uses methods or creates an instance of the included class?

Comment: It's strange that you had to add those rules; Make has an implicit rule for building `%.o` from `%.cpp`, so it shouldn't be necessary. as for the `#include`'s, yes, there's a better way: if `StatTests.cpp` uses instances of `KS` and calls `KS::foo()` but *`StatTests` does not have a `KS` member`*, then you can forward-declare `KS` in `StatTests.h`, and `#include KS.h` in `StatTests.cpp`. That way `main.o` doesn't (necessarily) depend on `KS.h`.